# montyhall simulator gone wrong(python)

Tags: python

```
#
# Monty Hall Problem Simulation
# Author: Ryan Sturmer
#

import random

def play_round(doors, switch):

    # Choose the location of the car
    car = random.randint(1, doors)

    # Contestant chooses a door 
    initial_choice = random.randint(1, doors)

    # Monty opens ALL the other doors except one
    if initial_choice != car:
        monty_leaves = car # If the car wasn't chosen, Monty is forced to reveal its location
    else:
        while True:
            monty_leaves = random.randint(1, doors)
            if monty_leaves != initial_choice:
                break

    # monty_leaves is now the door that Monty DIDN'T open
    if switch:
        final_choice = monty_leaves
    else:
        final_choice = initial_choice

    victory = (final_choice == car)

    return victory, initial_choice, final_choice, car

def simulation(iterations, doors=3):
    games_won_switch = 0
    games_won_noswitch = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        won_game, intial_choice, final_choice, car = play_round(doors, False)
        if(won_game):
            games_won_noswitch += 1
        won_game, intial_choice, final_choice, car = play_round(doors, True)
        if(won_game):
            games_won_switch += 1

    print ""
    print "            Monty Hall Simulation"
    print "---------------------------------------------"
    print "                        Iterations: %d" % iterations
    print "    Games won when switching doors: %d (%g%%)" % (games_won_switch, 100*float(games_won_switch)/float(iterations))
    print "Games won when NOT switching doors: %d (%g%%)" % (games_won_noswitch, 100*float(games_won_noswitch)/float(iterations))
```

===========================================================================

I found this code from github. 
When I run this code, the sum of games_won_switch and games_won_noswitch is not equals to iteration. 
(For example, if I set iteration 1,000 -> it appears 996, 1,001, 1,008 not exact 1,000)

How can i fix problem this up?

Comment: Why do you expect them to sum exactly to 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake in the code; it runs the simulations twice:

Once when the player chooses to switch doors every time, and another time when the player chooses to never switch doors. It then prints the results of both simulations.

The results are from independent simulations.

```
for i in range(iterations):

    # Sim with player choose to open the door each time
    won_game, intial_choice, final_choice, car = play_round(doors, False) 
    if(won_game):
        games_won_noswitch += 1

    # Sim with player choose NEVER to open the door
    won_game, intial_choice, final_choice, car = play_round(doors, True)
    if(won_game):
        games_won_switch += 1
```

In consequence, because `sim(open=True)` is not `(1 - sim(open=False))`, but result from two sets of simulations, the addition of results may not add up precisely to the number of trials.

Comment: Thank you for your help.